# Does Haskell have a takeUntil function?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Currently I am using

```
takeWhile (\x -> x /= 1 && x /= 89) l
```

to get the elements from a list up to either a 1 or 89. However, the result doesn't include these sentinel values. Does Haskell have a standard function that provides this variation on `takeWhile` that includes the sentinel in the result? My searches with Hoogle have been unfruitful so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you were asking about standard functions, [no](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch20.html#x28-22800020). But also there isn't a package containing a `takeWhileInclusive`, but that's really simple:

```
takeWhileInclusive :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeWhileInclusive _ [] = []
takeWhileInclusive p (x:xs) = x : if p x then takeWhileInclusive p xs
                                         else []
```

The only thing you need to do is to take the value regardless whether the predicate returns True and only use the predicate as a continuation factor:

```
*Main> takeWhileInclusive  (\x -> x /= 20) [10..]
[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

Comment: I'm new enough to Haskell that it's probably a good exercise to implement these things myself anyway. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but his function doesn't quite do what is requested generally even though it works for this specific case .... for example `takeWhileInclusive (>1) [2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]` would return the whole list which is not quite `takeWhile + sentinel`

Comment: @matt err, no. `takeWhileInclusive` does only return the first sentinel, not the whole list: https://ideone.com/wD0ULx. There's only a single `1` (the sentinel) in the result.

Comment: sorry, I meant `(>=1)` in that case.. it is not `takeWhile + sentinel` ... for example you could not use it to take while a `collatz` function

Comment: @matt With `(>=1)`, all elements would fit the predicate, and `takeWhile (>= 1) xs == takeWhileInclusive (>= 1) xs` for `xs = [2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1]`. You probably want to ask a new question for your problem, though.

Comment: I am not asking a question other than asking if this actually meets the spec of the question. Anyway, if you think it does I guess that is fine.

Answer (score 5):

Is `span` what you want?

```
matching, rest = span (\x -> x /= 1 && x /= 89) l
```

then look at the head of `rest`.

Comment: In that case I think you need `span` instead of `break` in order to comply with OP's specification.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. It had just occurred to me that `break`'s predicate is reversed, but I didn't know `span`. I'll update the answer accordingly!

Comment: @sanityinc: I also had that one in mind, but you need to take a little bit of caution since `rest` could be `[]`.

Comment: @Zeta Yes indeed -- I avoided a cons match on `rest` in the example for that reason. Your explicit solution is likely a better choice overall.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way I found to achieve that is using **span** and adding a function before it that takes the result of span and merges the first element of the resulting tuple with the head of the second element of the resulting tuple.
The whole expression would look something like this:

```
(\(f,s) -> f ++ [head s]) $ span (\x -> x /= 1 && x /= 89) [82..140]
```

The result of this expression is

```
[82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89]
```

The first element of the tuple returned by span is the list that takeWhile would return for those parameters, and the second element is the list with the remaining values, so we just add the head from the second list to our first list.

Comment: Try calling it with an empty list. See what goes wrong?