# Equivalent in Haskell of generator with stopping condition

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, generator

Suppose I want to build a list `iterate step x0` in Haskell, but with an inclusive termination condition. So in Python this would be `list(my_gen)` where e.g.

```py
def my_gen():
    x = x0
    while not done(x):
        x = step(x)
        yield x
```

(**Edit:** This should have an additional `yield x` before the loop if I want to include `x0`.)

One way would be to write my own [takeWhileInclusive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472536/does-haskell-have-a-takeuntil-function) and say

```haskell
takeWhileInclusive (not . done) . iterate step x0
```

Is this the Haskell-y way (or *a* Haskell-y way) to accomplish this? It seems unnatural to try to tack on some sentinel value for `step x` when `done x` is true and then use `takeWhile`.

In particular I'm thinking of the [container with most water problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water/) on LeetCode, and solving it with something like

```hask
maxWith volume . smartSteps (0, n)
 where smartSteps = takeWhileInclusive (\(i,j) -> j - i > 1) . iterate step
```

and `step` increases `i` or decreases `j` (or both), according to which index has the higher line.

Of course here it would be easy to just use `takeWhile` j > i, but I wanted to think how I would approach situations where there isn't a natural "you went too far" condition, just a "you are done" condition.

**Edit:** This question has been marked as a duplicate (of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472536/does-haskell-have-a-takeuntil-function) which I had linked to in my question), but it is not. The question is not how to write `takeWhileInclusive`, in fact the question explicitly takes `takeWhileInclusive` as given. It is about how to accomplish a task that may or may not use `takeWhileInclusive`.

Comment: define `takeUntil done xs = foldr (\x r -> if done x then [x] else x : r) [] xs`. then use `takeUntil done $ iterate step x0`. e.g. `takeUntil (>9) [1..] == [1..10]`

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for the comment. But the question assumes a definition of `takeWhileInclusive` AKA `takeUntil` is given, and isn't about implementing that function.

Comment: so what is the question then? you wrote `takeWhileInclusive (not . done)` and asked whether it is "Haskell-y", right? and I proposed to use `takeUntil done` instead, with the corresponding tweak to the definition. You also asked for the definition with unfoldr, under an answer below. that's why I included this definition with foldr, to show you. to do this with unfoldr is quite convoluted, IIRC. but it is natural to do with foldr.

Comment: @WillNess On second thought, your suggestion helped me to understand better how one can use `foldr` to "terminate" calculations, and I think is the best answer so far. Thank you! If you don't care to post an answer, I'll write up your comment as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I can post it if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define

```
takeUntil done xs = 
  foldr (\x r -> if done x then [x] else x : r) [] xs
```

and then use it like

```
takeUntil done $ iterate step x0
```

e.g. `takeUntil (> 9) [1..] == [1..10]`.

It's easy to specify the final element with `foldr` (as is seen here), but more cumbersome to do that with `unfoldr` which encodes an "anamorphism", closing the generated list with an *empty* list as the sentinel. Specifying the non-empty tail is possible with an "apomorphism", which seems like it would be the fitting tool for this task.

Comment: Thank you. I also wanted to attach to this answer, for future viewers, your comment that `unfoldr` is cumbersome to use for this purpose.

Comment: re my "cumbersome" claim, [_this_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519530/slightly-generalizing-unfold/24540087#24540087) is what I had in mind. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `unfoldr` to generate the sequence:

```
unfoldr (\x -> if done x then Nothing else Just (x, step x)) x0
```

For example,

```
> import Data.List
> step = (+1)
> done = (> 10)
> x0 = 0
> unfoldr (\x -> if done x then Nothing else Just (x, step x)) x0
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

`unfoldr` calls its function on `x0` to start. When the function returns `Nothing`, `unfoldr` stops. When the function returns `Just (x, y)`, it appends `x` to the result and calls the function again on `y`.

Compare your generator to a Python implementation of `unfoldr`:

```
def unfoldr(f, x):
    while True:
        if (y := f(x)) is None:
            return
        else:
            yield y[0]
            x = y[1]

list(unfoldr(lambda x: None if done(x) else (x, step(x)), x0))
```

Comment: Thanks! Your use of `unfoldr` seems to prevent including the value that is `done`. (That's why I used `takeWhileInclusive`.) Is there a way to modify it to accommodate that case?

Comment: `\done -> unfoldr (...) x0`? For the example, I just assume that `done` is a free variable bound to an appropriate predicate (just as `step` is a free variable bound to an appropriate "advancer" to generate the next value to consider).

Comment: Yes, I assumed that, too. I think I didn't communicate clearly. What I mean is, in this framework, once `done x` is true, I want to include that `x` value as the last value in the list. Can `unfoldr` accommodate that easily? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is a Haskell-y way.

Another Haskell-y way (or a Haskell-y way to implement `takeWhileInclusive`) is to zip up the `iterate`d values with one step later.

```
myGen done step = map snd . takeWhile (not . done . fst) . ap zip tail . iterate step
```

N.B. unlike `iterate` (but like `my_gen`) this does not emit the initial `x` value as one of the steps.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Meant to include the initial `x` value.